# Hapijs proxy : subdomain routing to maindomain/subdomain

Tags: proxy, subdomain, reverse, hapi.js

1. main domain  : "mymain.com"
2. sub domain   : "subdomain.mymain.com"

when i get call from subdomain.mymain.com , i would need to display in browser contents from mymain.com/somepath/subdomain.

i would like to use proxy options in hapi-js and do the above . But with 
code like

```
config: {

  handler: function(request, reply) {

    let hostValue = request.headers.host;
    let path = request.params.path;
    let subdomain = hostValue.split('.')[0];

    return reply.proxy({
      uri: 'http://mymain.com/somepath/subdomain'
    });
  } \/\/end of handler
} //end of config
```

i am not able to achieve it . Just page is empty. This is angular based project and angular route does not get executed for this.

But if do for url : subdomain.mymain.com the below

```
return reply.proxy({
  host: 'mymain.com',
  port: 80,
  protocol: "http"
});
```

It works fine. Any clue how get this subdomain issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you're not placing the value of `subdomain` into the url, change it to look like this:

```
config: {

  handler: function(request, reply) {

    let hostValue = request.headers.host;
    let path = request.params.path;
    let subdomain = hostValue.split('.')[0];

    return reply.proxy({
      uri: 'http://mymain.com/somepath/'+subdomain
    });
  } \/\/end of handler
} //end of config
```

Changing this line:

```
uri: 'http://mymain.com/somepath/subdomain'
```

to this:

```
uri: 'http://mymain.com/somepath/'+subdomain
```

---

Alternatively, to clean up a bit, you could try using the `mapUri` config option of h2o2. Something like this:

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: {
    proxy: {
      mapUri: function (request, callback) {
        let hostValue = request.headers.host;
        let subdomain = hostValue.split('.')[0];
        console.log('proxying for', subdomain)
        callback(null, 'http://mymain.com/somepath/'+subdomain);
      }
    }
  }
});
```